# Не получается создать проект с MAUI в Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio, maui

В процессе реализации своего приложения на MAUI пришло обновление Visual Studio, я это увидел, обновился, пытаюсь открыть свой проект, а вс пишет, что не получилось загрузить проект. Я уже видел решения для такой проблемы и я проверял, в пафе есть нужный путь

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну я подумал, не так уд велика потеря, пересоздам проект, скопирую код, все будет хорошо. Пытаюсь создать новое приложение MAUI, а его нельзя выбрать. Его там тупо нету. Ни по поиску, ни если руками листать. Естественно у меня 100% был выбран C# в качестве языка, в инсталере все было правильно, я даже пытался откатывать к прошлой версии и переустанавливать вску. Что здесь можно сделать для починки вски?

Comment: Пробовали SDK переустановить? Его отдельно с сайта Майкрософт можно скачать

Comment: @tym32167 Вы знаете, да, пробовал

Comment: Именно ту версию, что у вас в проекте? Там вроде надо номер версии тот же чтобы был

Comment: @tym32167 нет, я установил новую версия(7), но я ничего не делал со старой. Если что уже установленная как то сама обновилась

Comment: Я бы снес обе и установил ровно ту, что в проекте используется.

Comment: Саму студию обновите, в установщике выберите компоненты MAUI. https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/maui/get-started/installation

Comment: @aepot Если бы все было так просто....

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio сообщает вам о том, что не может найти нужный SDK пакет. Попробуйте переустановить .NET SDK (или .NET Framework, не знаю какая именно платформа вам нужна) и тогда у вас всё должно заработать.
[.NET SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download)

В случае если у вас всё еще ничего не сработало, попробуйте нашаманить с PATH.
Его можно найти так: ПКМ по "Этот компьютер" - Свойства - Листаете вниз и находите "дополнительные параметры системы" - В открывшемся окне нажимаете "Переменные среды"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В открывшемся окне измените переменную Path (ту что в системных переменных) и вставьте путь до вашего .NET (у меня это C:\Program Files\dotnet)

Дайте обратную связь, если это не сработало.

Comment: Нет, не сработало. С рафом я шаманил, от там всегда был. И 6 и 7 дотнет я переустанавливал. Я даже подумал, что может я где то галочку при установке убрал(на ксамарине она у меня не стояла) и установил все доступные части маюи. Ничего не помагает